# Why does my computer shut down after gaming for a long period of time?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

```
Computer Specs: 
Intel Core i7-8700K
motherboard asus prime B360-PLUS
2x DDR4 8GB each
NVIDIA 1050Ti
PSU 550W corsair
```

Computer was working fine for 2 weeks until I decided to test some games on it. After around 4 hours the PC shut down on it's own. I attempt to start the computer back up, but the computer would not boot up.

I tested my PSU on another computer and the computer booted up.

After unplugging the main PSU cables from the motherboard and plugging them back in did the computer finally boot back up.

I re-tested the computer again and it still shuts down while gaming. I didn't notice any temp issues as my graphics card stayed at 30 degrees celsius and the CPU reached around 78 celsius.

Why does my computer shut down after gaming for a long period of time?
Why does my PSU cables need to be removed and plugged back in, in order to work again?

Comment: Can you please explain how this is too broad exactly? Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …computer hardware. The guy gave you the hardware, in detail exactly what he has tried. What more do you want from him? Really confused.

Comment: @Sickest, please see [Editing of recently closed questions](https://meta.superuser.com/q/13646/364367).  re: your question above, can you give a definitive answer to this question based on the information presented, that is within the intended scope of an answer?

Comment: @fixer1234 according to that logic, every single "Computers restarting" question should be placed on hold until the OP eliminates all possible situations until we can give him a definite answer. Is that what you're saying? Because i'll start putting in work to close all 'PC Restart' questions to be closed.

Comment: @Sickest, nope, not what I'm saying, and this discussion isn't constructive.